# UDF formatted hard disk reported full on windows 8.1 after having been modified on Debian

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, udf

I bought a new usb hard drive for backing up some data, i decided to format it to UDF since it suits my needs and it's a fully open standard. I formatted it on windows 8.1, using UDF 2.01 for best compatibility. I successfully wrote some data to it using windows, then i decided to try it on debian jessie, i was able to read and write to it without any problem. Unfortunately, when i put it back on windows, the disk is reported full, 0 bytes available for writing. It looks like Debian closed the disk as if it was a DVD-R that can be written only once.

Any hint?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it back in Linux to see if it was R/W for Linux only?

Comment: interesting, i just tried it and the file explorer keeps loading forever without showing the drive content..

Comment: ok, it works fine on linux, i can add files and delete data on the disk. It seems like Windows doesnt like the interaction..

Comment: I suspected that may be the case. I had a similar issue and went with http://www.ext2fsd.com/ for their drivers for Windows. Different file system but native on Linux. 3 works well and basic, 4 has better features. The reformat was worth it. Note: I was using Windows 7, it claims Windows 8 support now.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the ext2fsd looks interesting! Which version would u suggest?

Comment: I thought UDF was best for read-only media like cd/dvd's... If you're backing up only windows files, leaving it as ntfs or fat would still be readable & writable in linux, fat probably more susceptible to damage. ext3 seems more resilient that fat, and ntfs needs windows tools like `chkdsk` to fix some errors if linux can't

Comment: @Xen2050 is basically right, when I was using UDF it was on a rewritable DVD. It meant I could keep adding and deleting files. It apparently works on others or you would not have gotten it to work on Linux or even been able to format it in the first place. Possibly an upgrade from the original specs but that is a speculation.

Comment: ext4 has journaling and is better. try ext3 if 4 does not work for you, but I would try that one first. If it fails in either case, it is a good format so it would be worth it to look for other drivers (google is your friend!) but this one has been great for me for a while.

Comment: @Xen2050 UDF is certainly not widely used for hard drives, but it should work just fine. It was made as a generic FS and then was adopted by DVD and CD, i liked the idea of being able to use an open FS compatible with different systems.. We are still not there yet! Jeff Clayton thank you very much for your suggestions, i will try tomorrow

Comment: Ah makes sense as to why UDF worked for you at least in part. I hope to hear good results!

Comment: ext3 has journaling too, but ext4 is supposed to be "faster & better"... and with higher limits.

Comment: @Xen2050 good to hear, thanks. It has been a while since I checked the ext3 specs.

Comment: ok, i realized that the safest way to go was to keep using NTFS, the linux compatibility is high nowadays, while i wasnt sure about the ext2 support on windows, thanks everybody! :)